# Google ReCaptcha in Jquery.validate as class rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, recaptcha

I'm making use of Jquery .validate to validate my forms and we are also using Google Recaptcha to provide a nicer way of detecting if the submission is from a human.

I prefer to validate my forms by using the class attributes on each element, and have applied a hidden text field from another tutorial online.

```
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
```

I have added a method to the validator, but it doesn't seem to work

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("hiddenRecaptcha", function(value, element) {
  if (grecaptcha.getResponse() != '') {
    return true;
  }
}, "Please confirm you are human");
```

Is there something Im missing when trying to add it this way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? because besides the question that if there is something missing, i don't see the issue..